# Running simple script meant to fix Mojibake with Python and ftfy gives "*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized ***"

Tags: python, mojibake, ftfy

When I run it nothing happens except `"*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized ***"`.

```py
# https://junschoi.github.io/posts/ftfy_guide/
import ftfy

def main():  # Added by pyscripter.
    pass

ftfy.fix_text('This text should be in â€œquotesâ€\x9d.')  # Copied from the web page.

if __name__ == '__main__':  # Added by pyscripter
    main()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, I would recommend the reading of Python [PEPs](https://peps.python.org/). It will help you with Python sintaxes and best practices on the language! Also, try to better post your question!

So, editing a little bit your code, I would suggest to do so:

```
import ftfy

def main():
    print_quotes = ftfy.fix_text('This text should be in â€œquotesâ€\x9d.')
    print(print_quotes)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I just execute the edited code above, and got `'This text should be in "quotes".'` as output. So, probably you can go on from this.